# How to create .help file for mac application help?

Tags: macos, apple-help

I am trying to make the help support for my mac application. I made the XHTML, HTML and the .helpIndex file. But I dont know how to make  the .help file. My question is what is .help file? and how to make the .help file?

I am studying in the [apple classreference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-TPXREF104) for doing this. Below is the stuff I have copied this link

Creating a Basic Help Book

Once you create the HTML files containing your help content, you must organize them into a help book. `To do this, create a help book folder and include the following items:`

My Question: How to create a help book folder. I cant understand this. I have just create a folder with somename.help and copied the files to it. But that is not working. whether it is the correct way of creating a help folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The .help is the top level folder of your document set not a file. Like a Mac application is really a folder with a .app extension

At a base level you need to create your html based document set like you have done and then add the `meta` tag named `AppleTitle` into your top level .html file index.html (SurfWriter.html in the examples)

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title>Foobar Help</title>
  <meta name="AppleTitle" content="Foobar Help">
</head>
```

- add `CFBundleHelpBookFolder` with a value of the name of your folder (Surfwriter.help) to your plist
- add `CFBundleHelpBookName` with a value of `Foobar Help` to your
  plist (matches the meta tag in your header)
- add a custom copy phase to put your .help document folder structure into Resources

Should just work after that.

Comment: What about `CFAppleHelpAncor`? Do we need set it in `plist` too?

Comment: Im using index.html as my root so no but if your root file isnt index then maybe you will need to set that key

Comment: In Yosemite (10.10.3) it seems a little different from the answer above; the difference for me was that `CFBundleHelpBookName` needed to be in the form: `com.myCompany.myApp.help`. And just in case anyone's updating their app and needs to register a new help book, I also trashed the `com.apple.help*` files in `~/Library/Caches/` (and then emptied the Trash).

Comment: What if I need my help file to be in a framework to share it with an extension? Can't figure it out what help directory to write into the Info.plist.

Comment: @VitaliiVashchenko You probably need to ask a new question for that.